# How can I type my viewChild to return a specifed `ElementRef` generic:

Tags: angular, angular-signals

With v17.2, when I use the new signal queries like `viewChild()`, I can access the `ElementRef` with :

```
matCardElt = viewChild(MatCard, { read: ElementRef });
```

But this returns a  `Signal<ElementRef<any> | undefined>` instead of  `Signal<ElementRef<MatCard> | undefined>`

How can I enforce the right generic for `ElementRef`, so I can get a `<ElementRef<MatCard>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently a [known limitation](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/53894) of the signal queries (`inject` has the [same issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/48126))

To returned the right generic type, you need to specify it yourself.

The signal query is defined as

```
<LocatorT, ReadT>(locator: ProviderToken<LocatorT> | string, opts: {
    read: ProviderToken<ReadT>;
}): Signal<ReadT | undefined>;
```

You need to specify `LocatorT` and `ReadT`, so in our case this would be:

```
matCardEl = viewChild<MatCard, ElementRef<MatCard>>(MatCard, { read: ElementRef });
```